# Adding Spinner ID to android:layout_below doesn't seem to work on Ice Cream Sandwhich

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am experiencing the weirdest thing.

When I try to create a spinner. if I do not give it the ID "test" I will always see an error that say's "Couldn't resolve resource @id/..." in the graphical layout tab. The error seems specific to the layout_below in he TextView that follows the spinner. Everything appears to layout properly in that tab though. When I run the app on any device that is honeycomb or earlier everything appears right despite this "error." However, when I then run the app on a the Ice Cream Sandwich emulator, I do not see the spinner anymore.

I need to add more than one spinner, so obviously I can name them all "test." Even naming them something like "test2" or "test3" doesn't work for me. I'm worried that this app will not be able to run properly on Ice Cream Sandwich

```
<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/test"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/PrevEditText"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt">
</Spinner>


<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/TextViewText"
android:layout_below="@id/test">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this as to why

http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields